# Show that $\sum ^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})^2}$=$\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that $\sum ^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})^2}$=$\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

i know that $ \sum _{k=1} 1/k^2 = \pi^2/6$ how to do prove this

Comment: Then you also know what $\sum(2k)^{-2}$ is, so you also know what $\sum(2k-1)^{-2}$ is, so you also know what your sum is.Work it out!

Comment: I would also add that your sum is not $\pi^2/6$, but $\pi^2/2+4$

Comment: I think it is just $\pi^2/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show that
$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})^2}
=\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}
$.

$$S
=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})^2}
=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}
=4\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}
.$$

So this is 4 times
the sum of the odd terms in
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
.$$

To get the sum of the even terms,
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^2}
=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4n^2}
=\frac14\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
=\frac14\frac{\pi^2}{6}
=\frac{\pi^2}{24}
.$$

Combine these two,
using
$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$
like this:
$\frac{S}{4}+\frac{\pi^2}{24}
=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$
or
$\frac{S}{4}
=\frac{\pi^2}{8}
$
or
$S
=\frac{\pi^2}{2}
$.

So your comment appears correct!

As a check,
$\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\approx 1.5
$
and
$S > \frac1{.5^2}
=4
$.

Comment: ...thanks but i didt get pi^2/6

Comment: You are right. I finished my derivation.

Comment: ...then what is the answer pi^2/6 or pi^2/2

Comment: $\pi^2/2$, because the sum is greater than the first term which is 4.

Comment: For question in its current form, the sum start at $n = 0$, the first two term is already $8 > \frac{\pi^2}{2}$.

Comment: You are right. I assumed the start was 1, not 0. I will change my answer correspondingly.

Answer (score 3):

You should note that $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$$

This shows that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Now recognize that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4}{(2k-1)^2}$$

THis should help lead you to your goal.

Comment: Fix the sums limits...

Comment: Thanks....watching tv so not fully engaged.

Comment: I also think the OP's limits are off. This sum should start at 2k-1 when k=1 not k=0.  Maybe if it were when k=0, 2k+1

Comment: Nice concise way to express it.

Answer (score 3):

Simplify the term inside the summation.
$$
\sum \frac{1}{(n-\frac 12)^2} = \sum \frac 4{(2n-1)^2} = 4 \sum \frac 1{(2n-1)^2}
$$
This is just the summation of squares of all odd numbers.

Now, use the fact that:
$$
\frac {\pi^2}6 = \sum \frac 1{k^2} = \left(1 + \frac 1{3^2} + \frac 1{5^2} + \ldots\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{6^2} +  \ldots\right)
$$

And finally, note that:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{6^2} +  \ldots\right) = \frac 14 \left(\sum \frac 1{k^2}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{24}
$$

See if you can finish it from here.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers seems to give the final answer, so I'll give it a try here:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\left(n-\frac12\right)^2}=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}=4\frac{\pi^2}8=\frac{\pi^2}2$$

and to this we must add the summand corresponding to $\;n=0\;$ , which isn't included there, so we finally get

$$\frac{\pi^2}2+4$$

The above uses

$$\frac{\pi^2}6=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}\implies$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}=\left(\frac16-\frac1{24}\right)\pi^2=\frac{\pi^2}8$$